# Set background with gravity without resizing the container View in Android

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout

How can I add a background to a view, without resizing its size, only showing the part of the image that fits the previous space?

Example:

I have the following initial layout:

[image]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#8900"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="com.tappx.myapplication.MainActivity">


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#fff"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:background="#0f0"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="HELLO" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:background="#f0f"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="HELLO" />


    </LinearLayout>


</LinearLayout>
```

And I want to apply the following image as gradient to the white background:

[image]

To achieve this (please note the gradient is filling the horizontal and has bottom gravity):

**TARGET:**
[image]

My problem is that setting the gradient as `android:background` expands the container view size to this (losing the red bottom part)

[image]

Also tried making a xml bitmap with no results:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <bitmap
            android:gravity="bottom"
            android:src="@drawable/gradient" />
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

How can I achieve it?

Comment: I'd guess that the problem is connected with Your LinearLayout height set to "wrap_content". Do you really need to use LinearLayouts? Maybe ConstraintLayout with horizontal guideline eg will be a better solution? In such case you'll be able to add your picture with its bottom glued to any particular view

Answer (score 0):

The image you are using is very long, and your container is set to wrap content and so it is expanding to accommodate the image.

Since you are already using fixed heights on the inner elements, you can simply set a fixed height for the container (200dp) and it'll work